# Which way is better for this method that writes to a file?

Tags: c#

A bit of a silly question but i really cant decide, which was is better?

Either:

```
// Writes a byte array at offset in file
public void WriteByteArray(string file, long offset, byte[] buffer)
```

but that will force the user to always write the file path, or have it like this:

```
private string path;

public string File
{
     get { return path; }
     set { path = value; }
}

// Will do the same thing as the method above just here,
// except it will use the path which was set via "File"    
public void WriteByteArray(long offset, byte[] buffer)
```

There are pros and cons for both. For the first way the pro is, if you want to write the byte array into different files then you can easily do:

```
WriteByteArray(file_1, 0, new byte[]);    
WriteByteArray(file_2, 0, new byte[]);    
WriteByteArray(file_3, 0, new byte[]);
```

but the con is, if you want to just write to one file then constantly typing that path or the string variable containing the path may make the code look a bit messy and unorganized.

The pros for the second way is basically the con for the first way all you do is:

```
File = "C:\\test.bin";

WriteByteArray(0, new byte[]);    
WriteByteArray(0xFF, new byte[]);    
WriteByteArray(0x2ACD, new byte[]);
```

but the con is the pro for the first way aka if you want to write the byte array into different file then you will always have to do `File =`...

Idk. Which is better? Which way is mostly used?

Comment: Personally I would prefer the first one, only as a static method so I didn't have to instantiate something first. But why not expose them both so the client can choose to either save the file path once as a property or pass a new file path? Why do you feel like you have to choose?

Comment: Consider the `File` class and the corresponding `FileStream` that can be Opened from it: effectively, both methods are exposed. One bound-to the open file, with convenience wrappers also provided (eg. `File.ReadAllLines`).

Answer (score 2):

Since you feel there are pros and cons to both, then just implement both. This seems like a case where there is sufficient demand for either option, and creating one does not preclude the creation of another.

Also, since the first one doesn't require any state variables, make it `static` so the caller doesn't have to instantiate something just to call it.

Then have your instance method (that uses the `File` property) call the static method:

```
class FileWrapper
{
    public string File { get; set; }

    public static void WriteByteArray(string file, long offset, byte[] buffer)
    {
        // The real work goes here
    }

    public void WriteByteArray(long offset, byte[] buffer)
    {
        // Just call the static method and pass the instance property for the file path
        WriteByteArray(this.File, offset, buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two interfaces are for entirely different use cases:

- The first method, which could be made `static`, is for writing a buffer to a file at once; there should be no continuations, because the same file could be written in between of your program's writing it, creating a confusion.
- The second method is for building a file incrementally from partial buffers. You set the file once, and then write to it until you are done. The class itself should have a `Dispose` method in order to participate in `using` statement.

Ultimately, the decision is up to you: pick the interface that matches your intended usage pattern.

**Note:** Note that since `offset` could mean an offset in a file or an offset in the buffer, consider renaming the second parameter to `fileOffset` or `filePosition`.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach introduces [sequential coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling), which is often an anti-pattern (and probably is in this case). It also introduces a global variable (see [global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)). So the first method is better (although there is probably a third option that is even better, such as creating an object like `FileStream`).

But assuming you want to choose from either the first option or second option, pick the first. If you are concerned about code turning out like this....

```
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, myArray1);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, myArray2);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, myArray3);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, myArray4);
```

...I suggest you do this (which will also perform better)...

```
var outputBuffer = new List<byte>();
outputBuffer.AddRange(myArray1);
outputBuffer.AddRange(myArray2);
outputBuffer.AddRange(myArray3);
outputBuffer.AddRange(myArray4);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, outputBuffer.ToArray());
```

Or

```
WriteByteArray
(
    someLongVariableYouDontWantToType,
    (new[] { myArray1, myArray2, myArray3, myArray4 }).SelectMany(a => a)
);
```

...both of which concatenate the arrays and write them all in one go. The latter will perform better, but not everyone finds that sort of LINQ code easy to read.

If you did not mean to concatenate, but wish to replace, you should of course just use [File.WriteAllBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect to operate on the same file multiple times, it may be appropriate to use a [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to solve this problem. Or maybe it isn't. But it's interesting to discuss and could work as a decent answer. Let's have some fun and check it out!

Under the builder pattern, instead of this

```
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, index1, myArray1);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, index2, myArray2);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, index3, myArray3);
WriteByteArray(someLongVariableYouDontWantToType, index4, myArray4);
```

You'd want your code to look something like this:

```
myFile
   .WriteByteArray(index1, myArray1)
   .WriteByteArray(index2, myArray2)
   .WriteByteArray(index3, myArray3)
   .WriteByteArray(index4, myArray4);
```

The first step is to create a type that will hold a string that is the file name. We want our own specific type for reasons that will become apparent in a moment. Here's a sample:

```
public class File
{
    public string Path {get; private set; }

    public File(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

You can use this class like this:

```
var myFile = new File("c:\temp\MyFileName.txt");
```

Now that we have a class, we can write an extension method on it:

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public File WriteBytes(this File path, int offset, IEnumerable<byte> buffer)
    {
        OpenFile(path);    //Just as an example
        SeekIndex(offset); //Just as an example
        Write(buffer);     //Just as an example
        CloseFile();       //Just as an example
        return path;
    }
}
```

The key here is the `return path` line. Because of that, you can chain these together. Now we can do this:

```
File file = "c:\temp\fileName.txt";
file
   .WriteByteArray(index1, myArray1)
   .WriteByteArray(index2, myArray2)
   .WriteByteArray(index3, myArray3)
   .WriteByteArray(index4, myArray4);
```

Why did we want to use `File` and not just a string? Well, it would be pretty gauche to write an extension method for string that only works on certain types of strings. Hence the file-specific type.

Now there is one more (small) problem. Each call to `WriteByteArray` will probably open the file and close it again, which seems inefficient, since we only need to do that once. So in keeping with the builder pattern, we can add another method to signal completion.

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public File WriteBytes(this File path, int offset, IEnumerable<byte> buffer)
    {
        if (!IsFileOpen) OpenFile(path);    
        SeekIndex(offset); 
        Write(buffer);     
        return path;
    }

    static public void Commit(this File path)
    {
        CloseFile();  
    }
}
```

...which you can use like this:

```
File file = "c:\temp\fileName.txt";
file
   .WriteByteArray(index1, myArray1)
   .WriteByteArray(index2, myArray2)
   .WriteByteArray(index3, myArray3)
   .WriteByteArray(index4, myArray4)
   .Commit();
```

This last part isn't mandatory, but may be a good idea if I/O performance is important to you.